# Building Xamarin Android on TFS - how to download Nuget packages

Tags: msbuild, xamarin.android, tfs-2015

I have a Xamarin Android project that I'm building on a TFS build server. The Nuget packages are not restored, and so the build fails with a bunch of "[filename] could not be found" errors.

I believe the problem is that for the Android build, you specify the .csproj file, rather than the .sln. The field is called "Project" on a Xamarin.Android build step. The automatic Nuget package restore only works if you load the solution file. If you directly build the csproj with MSBuild.exe, the Nuget package restore does not happen.

I expect I can create a PowerShell script step that manually calls Nuget, but it seems this should be supported first-class. Any ideas for me?

Comment: Did you try the Nuget |nstaller build step?

Comment: No I did not. Found it and it works great. Strange that none of the demos, samples, or the default New > Build for Android include this step. It seems that an Android build will not work without it... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to add a NuGet Installer build step before the actually build step. More about this package [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer)